# Flask + Gunicorn + Docker - no module named api

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I Try to run flask on gunicorn in docker
Project structure:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEpcD.png)

Docker config:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /api

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
COPY ./api ./
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

ENV FLASK_APP=.
ENV FLASK_ENV=development
ENV DATABASE_URL=postgresql://fs_integr:fs_integr@db:5432/fs_integr


# CMD [ "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=5000"]

# CMD "export FLASK_APP=/api/__init__.py"
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":5000", "-e", "FLASK_APP=.", "wsgi:app"]
```

Error:

```
File "/api/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
api_1  |     from api import app
```

WSGI file:

```
from api import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I know what truth is close but I lost few hours already(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gunicorn can understand where to find api module imported in WSGI file if we run it from the outside folder following by name convention to file. So CMD command for dockerfile should be like this:

```
 CMD cd .. && gunicorn -b :5000 api.wsgi:app
```

`cd ..` - go out from api folder

`&&` - execute bash command one after another

`gunicorn -b :5000 api.wsgi:app` - run gunicorn, bind port, set_path:run_flask_app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).